# All content in a block with "transform" is distorted

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

Below, you can see two same figures (rhombus). All content in 2nd and 4th blocks is distorted. 
It happens because of one of the following reasons:

- If `.outer` div has `overflow: hidden;`
- If `.content` div has `transform: rotateY(0deg)` or `backface-visibility: hidden;` (in Chrome)
- If `.content3d` div has `transform-style: preserve-3d;` (in Firefox)

How to fix it without removing the css properties that are mentioned above?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  margin: -20%;
}
.outer {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 50px;
}
.inner {
  line-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
.content3d {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.content {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/12/25/13/07/plant-1107586_960_720.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content3d">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/12/25/13/07/plant-1107586_960_720.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer" style="clear: both;">
    <div class="inner">
        TEXT
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content3d">
            <div class="content">
                TEXT
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your transforms are causing the issue:

```
.content {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

It doesn't look like they are doing anything, why do you have them in there?

Comment: I use the [css flipping animation](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) and I need to use this property.